# Desktop windows frozen and panels disappeared after installing gnome-shell 3.2

Tags: gnome

I've recently performed a clean install of Oneric Ocelot from Live CD (after formatting my hard-disk and creating new partitions). One of the new things I decided to install was the gnome-shell and gnome-tweak-tool, since I wanted much more control than what the unity offered. So, I installed both gnome-shell and gnome-tweak-tool by using apt-get install. However, I'm facing two issues while logging in to my new gnome 3.2 shell:

[1.] The top-panel and bottom status-panel have both disappeared. (screen-1)

[2.] When I open a window, it becomes frozen i.e. it cannot be moved or resized - and does not have a close/minimize button. (screen-2)

screen-1:
[image: Screen-1]

screen-2:
[image]

Also, this does not happen when I login using the "Gnome Classic" or "Gnome Classic (No Effects)" shell. One more issue is that the extensions list is empty in the gnome-tweak-tool though I have installed all the extensions, but that is another one to solve once this first obstacle is over.

Hope you can illuminate me in this regards!

Comment: You'd be better off asking this on Super User, since it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes! I had same problem with Gnome- Shell. What I found was, It was happening cause of gnome-shell Extensions that I installed after installing Gnome-shell. When I removed all of the Extensions( using Unity mode ). It started working. So, when I reinstalled them ( Extensions) and again turned them ON using Gnome-tweak Tool, It happened again.

then I googled the problem, and the solution I found there is to " Set a profile Picture of your account " and It start working...nothing happening now..I hope It will help